# LinkedIn oauth failure from Firebase functions example

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, linkedin-api

I am following the directions at: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth.  I have my function deployed along with this static page: https://quantum-episode-826.firebaseapp.com.  However, when I click on the "Sign in" button I get the error: "Bummer, something went wrong. The redirect_uri does not match the registered value."

In the readme it says to:

[image: readme-instruction]

which I believe I have done correctly:

[image: linkedin-auth-redirect]

Any next step suggestions for troubleshooting would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from an issue with a Google node runtime process variable.  Appears that everything else was correct.